# if condition being executed even when conditions aren't meet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on React-native and for some reason I think my programme is running body of if-statement even when conditions aren't fulfilled

So this is what I have

```
  if (!this.props.exhangeSort && !this.props.exchangeError) {
            console.log(this.props.exchangeSort) //Line 72
            console.log(this.props.exchangeError) //Line 73
```

Here I am using  `&&` and so I am expecting it to run when both `this.props.exhangeSort` and `this.props.exchangeError`are false

But when I check my `console.log`after it throws an error

I am seeing the response from **line 72 to be True and from Line 73 to false**

**Question:** Since response from Line 72 is True, **Shouldn't it not run**/log/go through the body of `if-statement`?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure these are boolean type? try to check **== false**

Comment: @NullPointer they are boolean type like for sure.

Comment: Since you're already using the debugger, set a break point on line 71 and examine the properties. There's something fishy going on here, but a bug this big in V8 would be a disaster, so I doubt the problem lies there.

Comment: @JonasWilms I am not sure what are getters/setters. Haven't used them yet :)

Comment: @JakeHolzinger doing that :)

Comment: I'd recommend adding a linter that highlights typos such as `exhangeSort` ...

Comment: I'd recommend running in strict mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at the conditions in line 71 again. There might be a typo in !this.props.exhangeSort when you probably meant !this.props.ex**c**hangeSort. If the property doesn't exist javascript might be returning an undefined which is javascript false-y.

Comment: Might be the answer if there is a property within props called exhangeSort which is a boolean that is false